# R: Construct a file path from user input

Tags: r, path, directory

I have two variables, `work.dir` and `my.file`. This means the user would like to save `my.file` to `work.dir`. User is asked to enter `work.dir` path and this is where it gets tricky. If user enters `work.dir` path

`c:/temp/`

and I try to `paste` this with a `my.name`, I will get

`c:/temp/my.file`.

But if the user enters

`c:/temp`

I will get

`c:/tempmy.file`.

So far I've been battling this with extracting various parts of the `work.dir` and sticking it together to achieve consistency, but I was wondering if there's another way (that would be perhaps more resilient)?

So far this has been my solution of getting a consistent directory that can be used to be pasted together with a file name.

```
work.dir <- "c:/temp"
work.dir <- paste(dirname(work.dir), basename(work.dir), sep = "")
```

Comment: I think `c:/temp//my.file` would be interpreted ok, so `paste(work.dir,my.name,sep="/")` should work in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James rightfully points out that in most cases the directory will be interpreted correctly. In case this doesn't satisfy you and assuming your user knows he or she shouldn't use backslashes in his directory, you can use `file.path()` to solve your problem, eg like this:

```
makepath <- function(path,file){
  path <- as.list(strsplit(path,'/')[[1]])
  do.call(file.path,c(path,file))
}
```

If your user might use Windows backslashes (and forget he has to escape them with another backslash), you can add the following controls:

```
makepath <- function(path,file){
  if(grepl('[^[:graph:]]',path)) 
    stop("Invalid characters. Check you didn't use a single \\")
  win <- grepl('\\\\',path)
  sep <- if(win) '\\\\' else '/'
  path <- as.list(strsplit(path,sep)[[1]])
  do.call(file.path,c(path,file))
}
```

This gives :

```
> makepath('c:\\temp','myfile')
[1] "c:/temp/myfile"
> makepath('c:\\temp\\','myfile')
[1] "c:/temp/myfile"
> makepath('c:/temp','myfile')
[1] "c:/temp/myfile"
> makepath('c:/temp/','myfile')
[1] "c:/temp/myfile"
```

Comment: No need to wrap it really. Using file.path is enought. R will even map stupid things like "C:\\temp\\\\/myfile" correctly.

Comment: @Hansi Might be, but if a package tells me a file is saved in 'C:\\temp\\\\/myfile' I ask myself what's wrong with that package. Plus, R does not interprete 'C:\temp\\myfile' correctly, and that's input you can expect as well.